# Polymorphism and Enums

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

Say I have a class structure like this:

```
 Public Class Student
    Public Enum Days
        Monday
        Tuesday
        Wednesday
        Thursday
    End Enum

    Public _Day As Days

    Public Shared Function Factory(ByVal StudentType As String, ByVal day As Days) As Student
        If StudentType = "PostGraduate" Then
            Return New PostGraduate(day)
        Else
            Return New Undergraduate(day)
        End If
    End Function    
 End Class

 Public Class PostGraduate
    Inherits Student

    Public Sub New(ByVal day As Days)    
    End Sub    
 End Class

 Public Class Undergraduate
    Inherits Student

    Public Sub New(ByVal day As Days)
        _Day = day
    End Sub
 End Class
```

Only the undergraduate class uses the enum, however the Enum has to be declared in the superclass (Student) because the factory method requires a Day to be passed to it.  Is there a way I can put the Enum in the Undergraduate class? Unfortunately you cannot inherit from enums.

Comment: Why can't you make the enum separate from Student? Day has nothing to do with student.

Comment: The current setup seems fine to me, why do you specifically want it to be restricted to `Undergraduate`? What actual benefits do you think it will give you? An `Undergraduate` is effectively a type of Student anyway, plus all your derivations of `Student` have a `New` method which takes in a `Days` parameter therefore it wouldn't make sense to restrict it to only `Undergraduate`.

Comment: @James,thanks.  I used the example above to explain the problem.  The enum is only relevant to the sub class in the actual system.

Comment: If the `enum` is only specific to `Undergraduate` then you have a design problem. I'd say remove the `Days` parameter from the factory method and perhaps use property injection instead.

Comment: SOLID Principles -> Liskov Substitution Principle -> "objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program."

Answer (score 1):

If `PostGraduate` does not need to use `Days`, then take out the constructor `Days` parameter but initialise `Days` to a default value.

This brings another very important point: **use a default 0 value for your Enums**, something like Unknown, NotSet or anything. Enum are just kind-of glorified `int`s, if you don't initialise them they start at 0, which in your case means `Days.Monday`... that is not what you want.

You should also make your `_Day` property as `public` get but `protected` set (sorry I don't remember the VB keyword, basically it can only be set by itself and derived classes).